# Which is better? Integer.valueOf(readLine()) or readLine()!!.toInt()

Tags: string, kotlin, input, integer, readline

I am learning Kotlin using codeacademy. In the Madlibs project I was asked to read an number input using readLine() from the user and then convert it to an integer. I want to know which of the two solutions is better moving forward.

This was my solution:
`distance = readLine()!!.toInt()`

This was the given solution:
`distance = Integer.valueOf(readLine())`

Comment: Also, consider using [`readln()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.io/readln.html) instead of `readLine()`. The former returns `String`, whereas the latter returns `String?`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`toInt()` is the better solution. It's in the Kotlin standard library, and `Integer.parseInt` is in the Java library. Always prefer Kotlin-only solutions over Java solutions, where available.